# Import AOSP project to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import

So I am trying to import Google Launcher3 to Android Studio.
I have downloaded onefrom Github, but it is version for Android M and I want version for Android N. How can I import it?

I need this one:
[link to source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/)

Answer (score 0):

Its always the latest one which is cloned until you specify a branch .